# Handling Images in PhoneGap

Tags: image, cordova

Current Behavior:

I have build a PhoneGap application that takes photos using Camera and the upload to a server. User can see all the photos that are uploaded as thumbnails.

What I am trying to do:
I want that the user should be able to tap on a photo thumbnail and the selected photo should open in the default image viewer for iOS/Android. Also, user should be able to swipe the photo in the default image viewer to see additional photos. This behavior is similar to what Facebook or any other app implements.

I am not sure how this feature is implemented and I am surprised that there is no one who faced this problem.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('file:///path_to_image', '_system', ' ');"></a>
```

I haven't checked it, but it should work fine.

Comment: It might just open one image, what if you have 10 images. I found a library called as image swipe. It actually works...